# Change content of div:before on mouse over another div is not working

Tags: html, css

I follow this example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19122409/2761794

Please view this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/pZr3c/

HTML:

```
<!-- This Works -->
<div class='container'>Mouse Over Here!</div>
<div class='test'>
    <div class='text'></div>
</div>

<br />

<!-- This not Work -->
<div class="container1">
    <div class='container2'>Mouse Over Here2!</div>
</div>

<div class='test2'>
    <div class='text2'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* This Works */
.test .text:before{
    content: 'Text2 Normal';
    color: red;
}
.container:hover ~ .test .text:before{
    content: 'Text2 Hover';
    color: green;
}

/* -------- */

.test2 .text2:before{
    content: 'Text2 Normal';
    color: red;
}

/* This not Work */
.container1 .container2:hover ~ .test2 .text2:before{
    content: 'Text2 Hover';
    color: green;
}

/* This not Works too */
/*.container2:hover ~ .test2 .text2:before{
    content: 'Text2 Hover';
    color: green;
}*/
```

First Example works perfecly, but second example dont work. I need use this with div inside div, but works only if div the div has not within another div. What's wrong? I would like if possible to use only css to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container1 .container2:hover ~ .test2 .text2:before
```

It doesn't work because `.container2` isn't a sibling element of `.test2`. Its parent, `.container1`, *is* a sibling therefore the following would work:

(`~` is a general sibling combinator - it only looks at sibling elements.)

```
.container1:hover ~ .test2 .text2:before{
    content: 'Text2 Hover';
    color: green;
}
```

I'm afraid what you're trying to do isn't possible in pure CSS since you can't transverse the DOM and there are [no parent selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) present. You would need JS to do that.

Comment: View this attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/pZr3c/1/ little issue, view this other: http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/pZr3c/2/ works on tag body, but dont work on any other tag... i try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/pZr3c/3/ but dont work too, If there is no possible way to do this with CSS, you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Works perfectly on example, but don't work for what I need, view this: http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/XLkRz/ check css, I need change text and color on mouse over, but dont work...

Comment: @rflfn Yea, it doesn't work because the HTML is different. Here is a jQuery solution - http://jsfiddle.net/625cc/

Comment: Thanks for you help! Your solution worked perfectly with Jquery, but am trying not to use any JS code in my theme in any manner thank you! I will guard it for another occasion.